# Embedding script for Google Calendar text description

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to set the description of a Google Calendar event to have a different selected presenter that is chosen in a rotatory manner (it is a slide deck that needs to be presented by a different person each week). The Python script specifying the rationale would work as the following

```
import datetime
people = ['Person 1', 'Person 2', 'Person 3']
year, week, day = datetime.date.today().isocalendar()
print(people[week_of_year % len(people)])
```

the resulting person from this calculation would show up in the calendar event description. Is there any tool to do that?

Comment: Do you want a tool that will do this, or do you want a sample code in python that allows you to add a description with `people[week_of_year % len(people)]` in an event?

Comment: @GiselleValladares the latter

Comment: posted a sample code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to create a recurrent event with different descriptions for each event.

However, I found a workaround for you using `Events: patch`. You first create an event using `Events: insert`, get the ID of the event you created with `Events: list`, and after that, then get the ID of the recurrences using `Events: instances`. Lastly, you use `Events: patch` to add the new description.

It might sound long, but I'm adding a sample with explanations on how to use it.

```
# impor the libraries that you will use for the calendar API

from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# The scopes that we need to use based on the Google documentation
# I added the information in the reference at the end of the answer

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']

# creation of the credential, I use as a base the Google Documentation "Python quickstart"

def main():
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # The list of people that will be use in each event 
        peoples = ['Person 1', 'Person 2', 'Person 3', 'Person 4']
        number_week = 0

        event = {
            # Event title
            'summary': 'Testing create description',
            # A test description will be replaced later, so you can add anything you want to it. 
            'description': 'test',
            # The start and end dates need to be in ISO-8601 date format
            # and the time zone needs to be formatted as an IANA Time Zone Database name, e.g. "Europe/Zurich 
            'start': {
                'dateTime': '2022-10-28T09:00:00-07:00',
                'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
            },
            'end': {
                'dateTime': '2022-10-28T17:00:00-07:00',
                'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
            },
            'recurrence': [
            # You can change the recurrence of the event 
            # for this example is a weekly event, and it has 4 recurrences
                'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=4'
            ],
            # The list of attendees
            'attendees': [
                {'email': 'test@email.xyz'},
                {'email': 'test2@email.xyz'},
            ],
            'reminders': {
                'useDefault': False,
                'overrides': [
                {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
                ],
            },
            }

        # We use insert to create the event
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
        # You can use the print in the next line to see the information about the event while you are testing
        # print('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))
        page_token = None

        # Search for the event, using the method list and the event title q='Testing create description'
        # you can use any other search key to get the event ID
        events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token, q='Testing create description').execute()  
              
        # get the ID of the event
        for event in events['items']:
            # print(event['id'])
            id_event = event['id']


            # Will search the ID of the recurrences of the event using the method instances 
            # e.g. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20221028T160000Z                    
            while True:
                recurrences_for_events = service.events().instances(calendarId='primary', eventId=id_event,
                                      pageToken=page_token).execute()

                # run the dictionary of each iteration     
                for recurrence_instance in recurrences_for_events['items']:
                    id_to_update = recurrence_instance['id']
                    # I used the next print just to review the IDs of each event
                    # print(id_to_update)

                    # Create the new body of the event with the name of the people in the list of peoples
                    # instead of using year, week, day = datetime.date.today().isocalendar(). I use a simple counter to iterate on the list
                    body = {
                        'description': peoples[number_week],                        
                    }
                    # update the event description with patch
                    updated_event = service.events().patch(calendarId='primary', eventId=id_to_update, body=body).execute()
                    # print(updated_event['description'])
                    # next patch in case you have a large recurrence of the event
                    page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
                    number_week += 1

                    # This will reset the counter, in case the number of people is less than the recurrences of the event
                    if number_week >= len(peoples):
                        number_week = 0

                if not page_token:
                    break
            

    except HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If the recurrent event has already been created, you only need to use the imports until the `number_week = 0`, and the part from:

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token, q='Testing create description').execute()
```

To the end, you might need to modify the for loop to only run once per recurrence.

**Reference:**

- [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python)
- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)
- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)
- [Events: instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/instances)
- [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch)
- [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html)